# In what circumstances should I provide two answers to a question? (if any that is)

Tags: discussion

I know that the feature is there, and pops a little warning dialog box, and my feeling is 'never' but I haven't found any examples, or much guidance.

For example, on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95596/is-there-a-single-word-for-a-document-containing-an-individuals-contact-informa/95617) about a word replacement for a 'contact details' page I've just posted an answer with two (in my op) rather different answers. The first is just me suggesting something that isn't *immediately* obvious if you're thinking of synonyms or related terms but that *is* a standard of sorts.

The second is me going nuts and suggesting something that's closer to the OP's original request, but that's not even close to a standard in the context, so it's more just fanciful free word association that may work.

I've put it together as one answer, but this got me thinking about whether or not this should've been broken up as two answers since (in my head at least) they're related only because I came up with them at about the same time, and well, that got me wondering what general guidance on multiple-answer policy might be.

Comment: We can't link questions directly to other questions on other sites, but this is covered by a [Meta.SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28471/two-answers-one-question).